# How to pass a variable inside the build method to its parent state in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a state that looks like this where I call the method `_getData` inside the *initState*

```
class _DataPageState extends State<DataPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedEvents = ValueNotifier(_getData(value!));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _selectedEvents.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  List<dynamic> _getData(DateTime value) {
    //trying to access 'events' variable here
    return events[day] ?? [];
  }
```

And my build method looks likes this

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _source = toResults(data);
    //'events' variable I'm trying to pass
    final events = LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<dynamic>>(
      equals: isSameDay,
      hashCode: getHashCode,
    )..addAll(_source);
  }
```

I'm trying to pass the **events** variable to my `_getData` method inside the state to be able to run it inside the *initState*, is there an appropriate way of doing that?

And if not, is there a way of moving the *final variable* up without having the issue of *"Instance member can't be accessed in an initializer"* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `build` method should be "pure", meaning it should not have side effects, since Flutter can call it whenever it needs to rebuild the widget tree (e.g. if a keyboard appears, if changing to landscape mode, because a parent rebuilds, etc).

In Dart, if you have a variable that will be initialized before it is first used, but cannot be immediately initialized, you can use the `late` keyword. Perhaps something like this would work:

```dart
class MyState extends State<MyWidget> {
  late LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<dynamic>> _events;  // late means no initializer needed

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final _source = toResults(data);
    _events = LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<dynamic>>(
      equals: isSameDay,
      hashCode: getHashCode,
    )..addAll(_source);
  }

  // other stuff
  
}
```

It's not entirely clear where `data` is coming from, but if it can be passed in from higher up in the tree, you could make it a property on the `Widget` class and use `widget.data` to read it safely inside `initState()`

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer + a few tweaks got me where I needed, I also needed to set an initial empty value for _events to not get any errors in case anyone encounters the same issue.